# How to make flutter screen unclosable?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-getx

I am working on a **flutter application**, where I made my custom **loading bar**, so whenever I set the value of loading bar **true*, it shown up. But the main problem is, when I hit the back button, It goes back and loading bar get closed. I want it to never close. And again, I am not talking about **showDialog** function. Please help me flutter developers. Thank you.

Comment: Please add Minimal reproducible code

Comment: I used Stack for that, I mean Stack contains 2 children, first the main page code, and second custom loading bar code, and I used GetX to show or hide the loading bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we're talking about `WillPopScope`. This will catch event your press back button in Android or swipe back in iOS. All you need is just wrap your `Scaffold` inside `WillPopScope`:

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        // do something...
      },
      child: Scaffold()
)
```

References:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html
- https://flutterservice.com/disable-back-button-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the widget `WillPopScope`: it prevents the user from closing/going back unless the condition specified in the `onWillPop` argument is `true`. Just set `onWillPop` to always return `false` , and you should be good to go.

See [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html).